# Best way to use existing PST in a new profile

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Due to a corrupt profile I am migrating to a new one. Ie, manually copying all of my data to the new folders.

Outlook needs to be reconfigured with the new profile. What is the best way to tell Outlook to use my existing PST?

I don't want to import...I simply want to point outlook to my old pst and have all new emails integrated.

Thanks for the advice, there are many mixed answers on the internet.

Comment: Have you tried simply placing (or copying) the original pst file in the current default directory?

Comment: You mean replacing the current PST with my old one?

Comment: Correct.  You can temporarily rename the current one to test.  If you want to keep both, you can open multiple pst files concurrently in Outlook (a handy tool to access archived messages or migrate selected messages to an "archive" pst).

Answer (score 1):

Although you would like to point to your old PST, I think it will be safer to perform an export of your old PST then re-import into your new profile. You can either overwrite your duplicates or not import duplicates. This is requires more steps, but could potentially save you from corrupt data (if any).

If you insist on using your existing PST file, run a SCANPST.exe to repair the file before you decide to use it as your main PST per fixer1234's comments about renaming the new profile PST to test then renaming your old PST to the new PST file.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

When you create a new profile Outlook forces you into making an email account. The trick is to tell Outlook to use an existing PST rather than create a new one.

I found out through trial and error that Outlook doesn't include a lot of meta data when you export. Using the original PST is the best way to make sure you retain your settings and restore functionality like auto fill etc.

Also, this method ensures that you don't needlessly create a second data file when all you need is the original.

If you already went through the account creation process you can delete the original and when Outlook opens it will ask you to locate the lost pst. Simply point outlook to the new PST and you're done.

Comment: Rather than delete the original PST, I'd rename it. This way, you have an opportunity to rollback.